# FULL Text Query using CONTAINS and phrase in variable (csharp; sql)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I would like to ask, which quotes do I need to use, if I have code like this:

```
cSQL += "CONTAINS (sectionArticleTitle, @SearchText) ";
```

For example,

if I have in variable SearchText phrase "with the" (without quotes), I need query to be:

```
SELECT * FROM ...... WHERE CONTAINS (sectionArticleTitle, '"with the"');
```

So I would like to know how I am supposed to add quotes in cSQL variable. I get syntax error if I use

```
cSQL += "CONTAINS (sectionArticleTitle, '"@SearchText"') ";
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single quotes do the trick. try the following code:

```
cSQL+=string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM CONTAINS(sectionArticleTitle,'""{0}""')", @SearchText);
```

Comment: I got syntax error... If I look closely on query it generated, it was like: ... CONTAINS (sectionArticleTitle, 'with the') and I need CONTAINS (sectionArticleTitle, '"with the"'). It was not syntax error in visual studio but fulltext error in database.